# terraform loop through ids list and generate data blocks from it (and access it again)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Is it possible to have a terraform list of ids (as string), like so:

```
locals  {
  secrets = [
    "cloud.secret.id1",
    "cloud.secret.id2",
    "cloud.secret.id3",
  ]
}
```

and create dynamically data for all those ids,

```
data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "basic" {
  for_each = toset(locals.secrets)
  secret = each.key
}
```

and then find a way to access a property inside each of those resources in the array again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `for_each` will result in `data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.basic` being a **map** with keys from your `locals.secrets`.

So you access it by referencing individuals elements in the map, e.g.:

```
data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.basic["cloud.secret.id2"].secret_data
```

or using `for_each` in some resource:

```
resourece "google_xxxx" "test" {
  for_each = toset(locals.secrets)
  secret   = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.basic[each.key].secret_data
}
```

Comment: @RicardoDuarte No problem. Glad it worked out.